# How to change Toplevel theme in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This code:

```
s=ThemedStyle(root)   
s.theme_use('black')
```

this seems to work with widgets that are related to instance `ttk` , but `Toplevel()` doesnt have any ttk instance, so is there any possible way to change `Toplevel()` theme?

Comment: I don't see, why it'll be of a problem. Wherever you say `ttk` it'll apply that theme, I believe. `Toplevel()` is a blank window and hence there is no real theme to be applied to a blank window?

Comment: @MinionJim, is there any secondary window(like toplevel) that work with ttk maybe?

Comment: In short: sadly no. Longer answer: take a look at the options (and lack thereof) on the [Tk toplevel man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/toplevel.htm) (I don't think `visual` is what you want but I really don't know enough about it). The only thing I can think of is use `overrideredirect` which I would not really recommend under most circumstances.

Comment: @CoolCloud you have reached to good conclusion,but when your main window has a theme and toplevel windows(children windows) has different theme, then it sound like something is missing,

Comment: One uniform theme for one instance, is the only possible way. Atleast it's what I believe

Comment: at least is there a possible way to make secondary window as a ``notebook`` rather than toplevel ?

Comment: What's the problem with using `ttk.notebook(..)` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud 2 problems, it doesn't have ```resizable()``` method, and window is not movable

Comment: I still cannot really understand the context for this, but if you are on MacOS, the latest Tk version has better support for dark-mode  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @minionjim I agree, I don't understand what exactly is intended by the OP, using `ttktheme` and `ThemedTk()` will apply the theme to all the child and `ttk` widgets.